# jquery show/hide div after form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I show loading message after form submit like this:

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none;"><img class='image-widthauto' src="/img/Progressbar.gif" /></div>
<div id="content-alert"></div>
<form id="login" method="POST" action="" onsubmit="$('#loading').show();">
..... //input
</form>
```

i validate my form using [jquery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login").validate({
        errorElement: "div",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo("div#content-alert").addClass('alert alert-danger');
        }, 
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                alpha: true,
            },
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "requied message",
                minlength: "6 character"
            },

        }
    });

});
```

Now, in form submit i see loading message and error box of validation(submit empty form value). i need to show loading message when my form not have a error using validation plugin.

how do fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `onsubmit` attribute, use the `submitHandler` callback of the validator

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#login").validate({
        errorElement: "div",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.appendTo("div#content-alert").addClass('alert alert-danger');
        },
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                alpha: true,
            },
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "requied message",
                minlength: "6 character"
            },

        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $('#loading').show();
            form.submit();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: This worked and show loading but in action not submit and not send data to server. after click submit i see only loading message.

Comment: how is the form submission done... is it done via ajax or normal form submission

Comment: in your demo if u click in submit jquery validation not validate form and send data without validatin. DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/mqfm730p/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try this : use `.valid()` method to decide whether to show loading message or not.

HTML :

```
<div id="loading" style="display:none;"><img class='image-widthauto' src="/img/Progressbar.gif" /></div>
<div id="content-alert"></div>
<form id="login" method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return showLoading();">
..... //input
</form>
```

jQuery ;

```
var form =  $("#login");

function showLoading()
{
  if(form.valid())
  {
   $('#loading').show();
   return true;
  }
  return false;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    form.validate({
        errorElement: "div",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.appendTo("div#content-alert").addClass('alert alert-danger');
        }, 
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                alpha: true,
            },
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "requied message",
                minlength: "6 character"
            },

        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to show the `element` with `id` *loading* when the form submits without an error.

[The official documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#submithandler) says :

> Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated.

So you could overwrite the `submithandler` like so:

Your html (just the form element, the rest could remain the same) :

```
 <form id="login" method="POST" action="#"> //Don't need the onsubmit here
```

Your javascript could be:

```
 $("#login").validate({
    errorElement: "div",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo("div#content-alert").addClass('alert alert-danger');
    }, 
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $('#loading').show();   //Show the required element here
      form.submit(); //Submit the form normally if needed
    },
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            alpha: true,
        },
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "requied message",
            minlength: "6 character"
        },

    }
});
```

Hope it gets you started in the right direction.